# Complie Error: Syntax Error or Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error "Last Row and CountIF"

Tags: excel, vba, countif

I am trying to add a countif to the row two rows below my last row of data.

I get and compile error if I include quotations marks around the criteria as I would do if I was adding the formula directly into Excel (This is the code shown). And I get a runtime error if I remove them.

```
Dim ARRow As Long
     ARRow = Range("T" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If ARRow < 2 Then ARRow = 2
     Cells(ARRow + 1, "T").Formula = "=Sum(T2:T" & ARRow & ")"
     Cells(ARRow + 2, "T").Formula = "=Countif(T2:T" & ARRow & ",">0")"
```

The last line is where I am getting the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quotes in strings need to be doubled-up to escape them.

```
Cells(ARRow + 2, "T").Formula = "=Countif(T2:T" & ARRow & ","">0"")"
```

Comment: **You Rock!** Thank you so much, brain is clearly somewhere else today